# Accessing textbox value in gridview header

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview that contains inventory data. I am trying to put together a search function that will create a SQL WHERE clause on the fly, based on the contents of each control in the gridview header.

Each column in the gridview is a template field, with the controls added in the Header Template.

This is my code. Whenever it runs, the control (in this case, chkCaseSearch) is null, and I get the "object reference not set to an instance of an object" error.

This is my C# code; it is located in a button click event (the button is also a control in the gridview header). Each control has an equivalent if statement, but I'm only showing one for the sake of brevity.

Thanks!

```
TextBox tbManufacturerSearch = gvFirearms.FindControl("txtManufacturerSearch") as TextBox;
TextBox tbModelSearch = gvFirearms.FindControl("txtModelSearch") as TextBox;
TextBox tbSerialSearch = gvFirearms.FindControl("txtSerialSearch") as TextBox;
TextBox tbCaliberSearch = gvFirearms.FindControl("txtCaliberSearch") as TextBox;
DropDownList ddlTypeSearch = gvFirearms.FindControl("ddlTypeSearch") as DropDownList;
DropDownList ddlFormSearch = gvFirearms.FindControl("ddlFormSearch") as DropDownList;
CheckBox chkCaseSearch = gvFirearms.FindControl("chkCaseSearch") as CheckBox;
TextBox tbMagazineSearch = gvFirearms.FindControl("txtMagazineSearch") as TextBox;
TextBox tbLocationSearch = gvFirearms.FindControl("txtLocationSearch") as TextBox;
TextBox tbCommentsSearch = gvFirearms.FindControl("txtCommentsSearch") as TextBox;

if (chkCaseSearch.Checked)
{
    strWhereClause = "[Case] = 1";
}
else if (!chkCaseSearch.Checked)
{
    strWhereClause = "[Case] = 0";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have to access it through the `HeaderRow` like so

```
CheckBox chkCaseSearch = gvFirearms.HeaderRow.FindControl("chkCaseSearch") as CheckBox;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are in a web environment, did you specify the ID tag in your aspx page?
If you are in a Winform app, it will be sufficient the (for example) `this.txtMagazineSearch` invocation to access the control properties.

Comment: It's web. I did add the ID tag:
`<asp:TemplateField>
                            <HeaderTemplate>
                                <br />
                                <asp:Button ID="btnSearch" runat="server" Text="Search" OnClick="btnSearch_Click"/>
                            </HeaderTemplate>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:LinkButton ID="lbtnSelect" runat="server" CommandName="Select" Text="Select" />
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>`

Answer (score 0):

The GridView control is a rendering tool for a dataset, so you can

- regenerate the dataset on the fly, and rebind it to the gridview, if you want to filter the informations
- iterate through the diplayed items, to evidence the one matching the criteria

In the first case, that I think is more pertinent, you can use in the "refresh" button OnClickEvent something like this:

```
protected void cmdRefresh_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionManager.getConnectionString("myDB"));
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("myQry", conn);
        cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        SqlDataReader rdr;

        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Par1", chkCaseSearch.Checked));
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }

        grdView1.DataSource = rdr;
        grdView1.DataBind();
}
```

You can substitute the stored procedure definition with a text containing the SQL command to launch.

Hope this help.

Paolo

Comment: So I can use the controls directly as parameters, without having to declare them outside of the gridview first? I tried to do something similar, but Intellisense said that the control didn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to specifically tell the gridview that the control I'm looking for is in the Header Row.

```
TextBox tbManufacturerSearch = gvFirearms.HeaderRow.FindControl("txtManufacturerSearch") as TextBox;
```

Even though there is only ever one control with that name for every iteration of the gridview, it still needed to be told what row specifically it was in.

Thanks!